# iMac 2011 21.5 Kernel Panic after upgrades (GPU k1100m) running Catalina, issue did not use to occur even after upgrade

Tags: imac, kernel-panic

Report

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff8002e469aa): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f83e38a9a, type 13=general protection, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x00007fff8fde0000, CR3: 0x00000004bee360c9, CR4: 0x00000000000626e0
RAX: 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f, RBX: 0xffffff802c7c2118, RCX: 0x000000000fd5ffff, RDX: 0x0000000000ae0000
RSP: 0xffffff8261512cd0, RBP: 0xffffff8261512cf0, RSI: 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f, RDI: 0xffffff802a402130
R8:  0xffffff802a402158, R9:  0xffffff802a402150, R10: 0xffffff802c819401, R11: 0xffffff802c8194d8
R12: 0xffffff802a402108, R13: 0x0000000000020000, R14: 0xffffff802c7c2118, R15: 0xffffff802a402130
RFL: 0x0000000000010206, RIP: 0xffffff7f83e38a9a, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x00007fff8fde0000, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0, PL: 0, VF: 0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8002b51220 : 0xffffff8002d1a65d 
0xffffff8002b51270 : 0xffffff8002e54a75 
0xffffff8002b512b0 : 0xffffff8002e465fe 
0xffffff8002b51300 : 0xffffff8002cc0a40 
0xffffff8002b51320 : 0xffffff8002d19d27 
0xffffff8002b51420 : 0xffffff8002d1a117 
0xffffff8002b51470 : 0xffffff80034c1a6c 
0xffffff8002b514e0 : 0xffffff8002e469aa 
0xffffff8002b51660 : 0xffffff8002e466a8 
0xffffff8002b516b0 : 0xffffff8002cc0a40 
0xffffff8002b516d0 : 0xffffff7f83e38a9a 
0xffffff8261512cf0 : 0xffffff7f83f16c03 
0xffffff8261512d90 : 0xffffff7f83e134bb 
0xffffff8261512ea0 : 0xffffff7f85913a21 
0xffffff8261513010 : 0xffffff7f858ab6e7 
0xffffff8261513080 : 0xffffff7f858ab5aa 
0xffffff82615130e0 : 0xffffff7f83deaf56 
0xffffff8261513170 : 0xffffff7f83dea87b 
0xffffff8261513210 : 0xffffff7f83df282a 
0xffffff82615132d0 : 0xffffff7f83e31cd5 
0xffffff8261513450 : 0xffffff7f83e331f7 
0xffffff8261513550 : 0xffffff7f842e64da 
0xffffff8261513580 : 0xffffff7f84307726 
0xffffff82615135c0 : 0xffffff7f842ebfb7 
0xffffff8261513600 : 0xffffff7f83f2a235 
0xffffff8261513680 : 0xffffff7f83f29f23 
0xffffff82615136c0 : 0xffffff7f83f2a4e6 
0xffffff8261513720 : 0xffffff7f84305ad3 
0xffffff8261513750 : 0xffffff7f84306113 
0xffffff8261513860 : 0xffffff7f842df73d 
0xffffff82615138c0 : 0xffffff7f84303570 
0xffffff82615138f0 : 0xffffff7f842a43c5 
0xffffff8261513930 : 0xffffff7f841c752b 
0xffffff8261513970 : 0xffffff7f842ed4ae 
0xffffff82615139a0 : 0xffffff7f842ed3a2 
0xffffff82615139c0 : 0xffffff7f84305681 
0xffffff82615139f0 : 0xffffff7f842f8e63 
0xffffff8261513a30 : 0xffffff7f841efc0d 
0xffffff8261513a80 : 0xffffff7f841f144d 
0xffffff8261513ac0 : 0xffffff800345397e 
0xffffff8261513b10 : 0xffffff7f841f1646 
0xffffff8261513b60 : 0xffffff800345cba3 
0xffffff8261513ca0 : 0xffffff8002e035e2 
0xffffff8261513db0 : 0xffffff8002d203c8 
0xffffff8261513e10 : 0xffffff8002cf6d15 
0xffffff8261513e70 : 0xffffff8002d0db22 
0xffffff8261513f00 : 0xffffff8002e2c065 
0xffffff8261513fa0 : 0xffffff8002cc1226 
    Backtrace continues...
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(14.0)[ECB33CB3-2FE3-3E99-A4E6-ED7C5DA6D543]@0xffffff7f83dc0000->0xffffff7f84097fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[44472E6F-8DA0-3B46-ADEF-AFF76EC6C6DB]@0xffffff7f83731000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(576.1)[2B5F4866-780D-3C79-A946-0E3F15D64FA9]@0xffffff7f83da4000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(576.1)[1279CBF9-88F1-3EB4-9566-1085DBF6DF8B]@0xffffff7f83d45000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(5.2.6)[E04CD680-EC03-39ED-99C6-902C8495543F]@0xffffff7f83db4000
         com.apple.GeForce(14.0)[5E15A31E-F9BD-389B-937B-917071F224E3]@0xffffff7f8429e000->0xffffff7f84339fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[44472E6F-8DA0-3B46-ADEF-AFF76EC6C6DB]@0xffffff7f83731000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(269.2)[2D5E86CB-6A2E-3B77-B030-40CC604ED887]@0xffffff7f83d14000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(576.1)[2B5F4866-780D-3C79-A946-0E3F15D64FA9]@0xffffff7f83da4000
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(14.0.0)[ECB33CB3-2FE3-3E99-A4E6-ED7C5DA6D543]@0xffffff7f83dc0000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(576.1)[1279CBF9-88F1-3EB4-9566-1085DBF6DF8B]@0xffffff7f83d45000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(438.7.3)[B263A05C-9992-3742-AD6C-295E68E22576]@0xffffff7f841c5000
         com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal(14.0)[D9BD5415-852D-3F99-B5D9-9E4FD7CABEEC]@0xffffff7f8588d000->0xffffff7f85a38fff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(14.0.0)[ECB33CB3-2FE3-3E99-A4E6-ED7C5DA6D543]@0xffffff7f83dc0000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[44472E6F-8DA0-3B46-ADEF-AFF76EC6C6DB]@0xffffff7f83731000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Dock
Boot args: -no_compat_check amfi_allow_any_signature=1

Mac OS version:
19H2

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Mon Aug 31 22:12:52 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.141.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 05D51A3D-3A87-3FF0-98C3-9CF3827A3EDD
Kernel slide:     0x0000000002a00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8002c00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8002b00000
System model name: iMac12,1 (Mac-942B5BF58194151B)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 487502210498
last loaded kext at 12216398214: >!A!BMultitouch    97 (addr 0xffffff7f86171000, size 57344)
last unloaded kext at 342842339608: com.hieplpvip.!ABacklightFixup  1.0.2 (addr 0xffffff7f86544000, size 24576)
loaded kexts:
com.paragon-software.filesystems.ntfs   106.5.15
com.objective-see.lulu  1.2.3
org.hwsensors.driver.GPUSensors 1802
org.hwsensors.driver.CPUSensors 1800
as.vit9696.WhateverGreen    1.4.4
as.vit9696.Lilu 1.4.9
org.netkas.driver.FakeSMC   1800
>!A!BMultitouch 97
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>AGPM   111.4.4
@fileutil   20.036.15
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!AMikeyHIDDriver   131
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.2.6
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.2.6
>!AHDA  281.52
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>!AHV   1
>!AMCCSControl  1.5.9
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.6f7
@GeForce    14.0.0
>pmtelemetry    1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!A!IHD3000Graphics 10.0.4
>!AMikeyDriver  281.52
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>eficheck   1
>!AFWOHCI   5.6.2
>!ASMCPDRC  1.0.0
>!A!ISNBGraphicsFB  10.0.4
>ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
>!ALPC  3.1
>!ASMCLMU   212
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!UCardReader   489.120.1
@filesystems.apfs   1412.141.1
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
|!ABCM5701Ethernet  10.3.5
>AirPort.Atheros40  700.74.5
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!AAHCIPort 341.140.1
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ABacklight    180.3
>!ARTC  2.0
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
>!A!ICPUPowerManagementClient   222.0.0
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
>!A!ICPUPowerManagement 222.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.6f7
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
@kext.triggers  1.0
|IOFireWireIP   2.3.0
>!AGraphicsControl  5.2.6
>DspFuncLib 281.52
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
|IOAVB!F    850.1
@nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal 14.0.0
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.7.3
@nvidia.driver.NVDAResman   14.0.0
>!AHDA!C    281.52
|IOHDA!F    281.52
@!AGPUWrangler  5.2.6
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.2.6
|IOFireWire!F   4.7.5
>!AThunderboltEDMSink   4.2.3
>IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
|IOSkywalk!F    1
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   7.0.6f7
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.6f7
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.6f7
|IO!B!F 7.0.6f7
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.6f7
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>usb.!UHub  1.2
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IOSurface  269.2
|IOAHCIBlock!S  316.100.5
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.1
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOAHCI!F   290.0.1
>usb.!UEHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UEHCI 1.2
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  576.1
|IOGraphics!F   576.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.120.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.120.3
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.140.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.120.3
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFile
```

Comment: You're running an unsupported OS & an unsupported GPU. What drivers are you using, Apple's or NVidia's?

Comment: apples, the k1100m is supported natively by macos

Comment: Where do Apple state it is supported? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208898 Even MacVidCards don't sell one & they're the recognised authority on 3rd party cards - http://www.macvidcards.com/store/c2/Nvidia_GPUs.html

Comment: Oh I see, 
I assumed it's natively supported as it's listed on this website: 

https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/2011-imac-graphics-card-upgrade.1596614/

Is it safe to assume I have a faulty GPU? I bought it second hand.

Comment: It ran perfectly up until last night...

Comment: All I can say is you're in uncharted territory. The usual start-point for kernel panics is to uninstall all 3rd party kexts. You have many, including the notorious hackintosh FakeSMC.